# Floating info menu in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want pixel information menu to float around cursor in Photoshop CS5. How do I do that?

The menu called Info or its contents is what I need to float.

[image: This is the info menu]

Comment: When you say, "pixel information," what exactly do you mean, or what information do you want to be displayed near the cursor?

Comment: This question needs to be much more specific. Expand it to explain what information you're looking to have displayed, exactly, otherwise I'll have to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It's simply not built into the application.

Comment: Well then are there any known plugins for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the info tab away from its home panel. This will make it float on one place and not collapse. But it's not going to move unless you move it.